# Bigquery Internal Error triggered by FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: join, google-bigquery

I am getting a Bigquery internal error when attempting to perform a full outer join. The query succeeds if I use an inner join.

The job statistics can be seen in:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/quantum-gearbox-90015/jobs/job_AQtc0zMEkDHkk-OmCXCGRk6zycs?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

The query is as follows:

SELECT
  CASE WHEN t1.userId           IS NOT NULL THEN t1.userId           ELSE t2.userId           END AS userId,
  CASE WHEN t1.jobId            IS NOT NULL THEN t1.jobId            ELSE t2.jobId            END AS jobId,
  CASE WHEN t1.result_duration  IS NOT NULL THEN t1.result_duration  ELSE t2.result_duration  END AS result_duration,
  CASE WHEN t1.job_submitted_ts IS NOT NULL THEN t1.job_submitted_ts ELSE t2.job_submitted_ts END AS job_submitted_ts,
  CASE WHEN t1.job_running_ts   IS NOT NULL THEN t1.job_running_ts   ELSE t2.job_running_ts   END AS job_running_ts,
  CASE WHEN t1.job_complete_ts  IS NOT NULL THEN t1.job_complete_ts  ELSE t2.job_complete_ts  END AS job_complete_ts,
  CASE WHEN t1.userId           IS NULL AND t2.userId            IS NOT NULL THEN t2.last_updated_ts
       WHEN t1.jobId            IS NULL AND t2.jobId             IS NOT NULL THEN t2.last_updated_ts 
       WHEN t1.result_duration  IS NULL AND t2.result_duration   IS NOT NULL THEN t2.last_updated_ts 
       WHEN t1.job_submitted_ts IS NULL AND t2.job_submitted_ts  IS NOT NULL THEN t2.last_updated_ts 
       WHEN t1.job_running_ts   IS NULL AND t2.job_running_ts    IS NOT NULL THEN t2.last_updated_ts 
       WHEN t1.job_complete_ts  IS NULL AND t2.job_complete_ts   IS NOT NULL THEN t2.last_updated_ts 
       ELSE t1.last_updated_ts END AS last_updated_ts
FROM (
  SELECT
    userId,
    jobId,
    result_duration,
    job_submitted_ts,
    job_running_ts,
    job_complete_ts,
    last_updated_ts
  FROM
    [activeJobs.jobScoreboard] )t1
FULL OUTER JOIN EACH (
  SELECT
    userId,
    jobId,
    result_duration,
    job_submitted_ts,
    job_running_ts,
    job_complete_ts,
    INTEGER(ROUND(NOW()/1000,0)) AS last_updated_ts
  FROM (
    SELECT
      userId,
      jobId,
      MAX(CASE WHEN eventType = 'WORKITEM_COMPLETE' THEN data.result.data.duration END) AS result_duration,
      MIN(CASE WHEN eventType = 'JOB_SUBMITTED' THEN timestamp END) AS job_submitted_ts,
      MIN(CASE WHEN eventType = 'JOB_RUNNING' THEN timestamp END) AS job_running_ts,
      MAX(CASE WHEN eventType = 'JOB_COMPLETE' THEN timestamp END) AS job_complete_ts,
    FROM
      [trebekProd.JobActivity_20151125T000000Z_20151126T000000Z@1448472935436-]
    GROUP BY
      userId,
      jobId))t2
ON
  t1.jobId = t2.jobId

Comment: The job query returns in part the following response:
 "status": {
  "state": "DONE",
  "errorResult": {
   "reason": "internalError",
   "message": "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed."
  },
  "errors": [
   {
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed."
   }
  ]
 },
 "statistics": {
  "creationTime": "1448477868181",
  "startTime": "1448477868667",
  "endTime": "1448477872929"
 },
 "user_email": "gquinones@brightcove.com"
}

Comment: Can you please give me your jobid so I can debug more efficiently? (Whoops. Sorry. Just found it in your link above...)

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your error was a temporary overload of our streaming ingestion service. It was unable to serve the data for your table at the time you ran your query because of the aggregate load on the system. We will investigate this further and fix the underlying issue. For now, if you run your query again it should succeed.